# Prediction of "trend"

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, predictive-models, trend

I have two time series who both have some fluctuation at level.

My question: I do have 240 obs. What do I have to do in order to show a "prediction" of the further development of each variable, based on their past values? Something like 3-6 periods forecasting would be great!

Comment: You need to be more specific. You could do one million different things, it's impossible to list them all here.

Comment: Let's say I want to continue the graph with dotted lines? (or draw confidence intervals).

Comment: If you had a model where the current values of the variables were functions of past values of these and perhaps also other variables, you could naturally use your model for prediction. Without a model your question is difficult to answer.